# Is this sentence correct

Tags: grammaticality

As informed by you we will keep the cheque with us once the customer lets you know if he will collect it from our office.

I need to know if I should keep the cheque or deliver it to the office where the customer will pick the cheque from.  So tell me if the above sentence is grammatically correct.

Comment: Are you asking whether the sentence is correct, or what it means? It appears that the company is asking for the cheque to be delivered to their office _if_ the customer wants to collect it from there. They seem to expect that the customer will tell _you_ if this is so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a reworded version of the sentence:

> Per your request, if the customer tells you that he would like to collect the cheque from our office, we will hold onto it until he comes to collect it.

If I were writing this statement for work, I'd emphasize clarity and make it obvious that I'm waiting for additional information. I might write something like this:

> You asked us if we would be willing to hold onto the cheque in our office and give it directly to the client. We would be happy to do this if it is the client's preference. Let us know what the client wants to do and we'll act accordingly.